# Airwatch android sdk development

Tags: android, sdk, vmware, airwatch

I've a simple android application that shows a web view

- android studio 2.3.3
- Airwatch SDK for android 17-2.9

when the app loads i get this error in the android monitor: 
**"E/AirWatch: Failed to match App certificate. Make sure your app is managed or AirWatch white-listed"**

I can't figure this out, is there something wrong with my **app profile** or i need to **white list my app certificate** some how?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZpYld.jpg)

Comment: Did you know? 
Formatting your details properly will help you get solution more easily.

Answer (score 1):

To get airwatch applications to work you must first upload it to your enterprise airwatch catalog then download that to your device.

Airwatch is a bit odd. You must first get the airwatch profile for that app downloaded, which can only happen by first creating it (by uploading the application for the first time) then by downloading the application from the catalog (the profile comes down with the app), then you can sideload the app whenever you want.

1. make the app skeleton
2. upload package to airwatch
3. download app using catalog
4. now you can test it
5. directly side load all builds from now on for testing

You should also know you can't really simulate airwatch applications

Comment: Hi, Every thing works fine now , but in android 7+ i get this error:

Comment: IllegalStateException: could not load open ssl